# Need to find the mode of a list of values (a map) in haskell

Tags: haskell

for example I have `[1,2,5,1,1,2]`, I have the function below,

```
card :: [Int] -> Map Int Int
card = Map.fromListWith (+) . (`zip`[1,1..])
```

that is able to give out this -> `fromList [(1,3),(2,2),(5,1)]`
and now I have to use this function in order to get the mode from these tuples, I basically have to get the maximum value from the key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [**`maximumBy :: Foldable f => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy)  to retrieve the maximum of the 2-tuples:

```
import Data.Function(on)
import Data.List(maximumBy)

maximum2Tuple :: Ord b => [(a, b)] -> a
maximum2Tuple = fst . maximumBy (compare `on` snd)
```

Now we can do this for a `Map a Int` by obtaining a list of 2-tuples that represent the key-value pairs. You thus can implment this as:

```
counterMode :: Map a Int -> a
counterMode = maximum2Tuple . …
```

where you need to fill in the `…` part as an exercise.

Comment: @programmer2000: you need to extract the key-value pairs from the `Map`